# hplot from bokeh isn't importing correctly to create a histogram

Tags: python, bokeh, ta-lib

I am receiving this error upon running my code. The main problem is that hplot isn't importing correctly.

```
  File "MACD.py", line 10, in <module>
  from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, hplot
  ImportError: cannot import name hplot
```

Here is my code:

```
macds = macd, macdsignal, macdhist = MACD(hloc, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
macdhist_f=[]
iter=0
for x in np.nditer(macdhist):
    iter+=1
    macdhist_f.append([iter,float(x)])
    print(type(x))
print macdhist_f

macdhist_df = pd.DataFrame(macdhist_f)

defaults.width = 450
defaults.height = 350

hist = Histogram(macdhist_df, values='macd hist', bins=50,
                title="MACD Histogram")
show(hplot(hist))
coin = "DASH_"
output_file(coin + "html", title="macd")
```

Comment: It looks like this was your first question! A few things -> from your Print statements, looks like you're using Python 2.x? Usually good to clarify, though it probably doesn't matter in this case. Also, your specific question is unclear from your title. It looks like you're getting an import error, which is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hplot` has been deprecated for a long time (you should have been seeing runtime warnings about this?) and it was recently removed entirely. The analogous function that you want is [`bokeh.layouts.row`](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html#rows), e.g.

```
from bokeh.layouts import row

show(row(plot1, plot2))
```

For more information about layouts in general:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html

Comment: the official online tutorial for bokeh still links to this depreciated version when you google it.

Comment: I'd love to try to change it but you will need to be more specific about the location, the exact search used, etc. Encourage you to open a topic on the project discourse: https://discourse.bokeh.org/